# iOS 7/8: How do I set the Navigation Bar to be pure white (#FFFFFF) and still maintain translucency?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios8

This is where I am currently (have removed the shadow line and have the desired translucency):

#### ACTUAL

[image]

However, as you can see, the navigation bar is not pure white. The OS darkens it slightly (`#F9F9F9`). I'd like a pure white instead like in the image below (mocked up on Photoshop).

#### DESIRED

[image]

I can get a pure white effect if I set `navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO` but then I lose the nice translucent effect. I need a way to get (a) a pure white nav bar, and (b) keep the translucency with `translucent = YES`.

Comment: @Caleb - They're not. Open them in individual tabs and flip back and forth.

Comment: @AndrewArnold Good tip -- I see it now.

Comment: @caleb is correct. Does the navigation bar go completely white when you scroll the contents of the collection view further away from the navigation bar? In my testing this is what I have found.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is not the color of the navigation bar, but the color of whatever is *behind* the nav bar. It looks like you have a collection view that, in the left hand image, is positioned so that the top is just below the nav bar. I suspect that the background color of the view containing the collection view is somewhat darker than "pure white," and that color is showing through the bar because it's translucent.

I'd try to fix this by either of two methods:

- Set the background color of the container view to white.
- Add an appropriate top margin to the collection view and have it extend under the nav bar.